# Spark plug noise on power supply

Tags: filter, noise, plug, spark

I am working on a motorcycle diagnostic tool. Everything works fine except for the fact that when the engine is turned on, in some motorcycles spikes start appearing all over the circuit, and the device LCD malfunctions. How can I filter this noise before it reaches the device's powersupply?

Here are two samples of the noise that I am receiving using an oscilloscope The peak voltage is probably higher and can't be seen due to oscilloscope limits:

[image]

I used an LC filter on the input of the power supply. It was fine when I simulated the circuit, but when I tested it on the device it made no difference.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5zjBo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I also used 5V TVS diodes in the circuit, after the device regulator but I'm getting the same noise all over the circuit. Any advice on how to remove the spark plug noise?

Comment: Without insight in the entire product, this is impossible to answer. First of all you need to figure out how the noise is coupled into the LCD interface, could be conducted through some cable or radiated through air. If filter on the supply lines does not help, it is somewhat likely that it is not conducted through the power supply lines.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny it is radiated through the power supply lines because when I use an oscilloscope on the power supply lines before they enter the device, the noise is also visible on the supply lines and much worse than inside the main circuit. Also when I move the device away from the motorcycle it makes no difference and the noise is still there.

Comment: Then you need to filter ALL the cables connecting the device to the motorcycle. Car and bike wiring is not designed to be spike free... too expensive, but the components filter the signals they need.

Comment: Placing that high capacitors, if they are electrolytics. is not a good idea for spike (or in general, common mode or differential mode noise) filtering. Because at spike frequencies (probably around MHz) the electrolytic capacitor will not be a capacitor due to imperfections. Place something in nF range. And also TVS or MOV may be needed across the power lines, and even the data lines.

Answer (score 2):

You’re facing the complex EMC problem of susceptibility to external emissions.

> How can I filter this noise before it reaches the devices powersupply?

The “noise” isn’t just on the power supply lines, it’s likely everywhere in your circuit and is being picked up by all the cabling you’ve got plugged into your device, and perhaps by inadvertently large current loops in the PCB.

An oscilloscope with a passive voltage probe isn’t a good device to measure this stuff. You’ll need differential voltage probes, inductive probes, and perhaps also a power meter or a spectrum analyzer to quantify any mitigation strategies properly.

Or you can just start slapping common mode ferrites on all the cables and see what happens. It’s mostly a workaround for the deficiencies of the design, is not pretty to look at, adds cost, and it doesn’t give you much help with a proper fix.

You’d have to reveal pretty much a complete “picture” of your design: the system diagram, physical layout of the device and all the cabling, how it’s situated when used on a motorcycle, etc.

As it stands, your question is way too broad to be answerable. I’d say: find an engineer with EMC know-how locally and pay for a couple of hours of their time to look at your problem in person. It would be the quickest way to at least get pointed towards a resolution.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of automotive electronics. Rest assured the next will be a little different.